# How to cause a running VB program to start from scratch again

Tags: vb.net

How can I restart a running VB program from within?
I have written a VB program that solves SUDOKU puzzles.
When it completes the solution, it asks if the user wants to run again with another puzzle.

I can not:

-determine the first line of code that the program executes. The main() is empty. All code is on the tab for Form1. I have tried breakpoints, but still can't determine the starting point.

-figure out how to cause the program to jump back to the starting point in the code.

Can you help me?

I've tried placing breakpoints in the code at places that might be close to the starting point, but so far that hasn't worked. When the program starts,  Form1 is displayed, and it is waiting to see if a check box gets activated, or if text is entered anywhere in many text boxes.

Comment: That's generally not a good way of achieving what you're trying. The best chance is to try to reset the data state to the starting point, that is in your case, to clear the sudoku board and all internal state used to solve it, and start from scratch again.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I am working towards implementing your proposed solution. Some success, but not all there yet.

Answer (score 0):

You should do what Alejandro said in his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57361655/how-to-cause-a-running-vb-program-to-start-from-scratch-again#comment101210108_57361655): "reset the data state to the starting point".

But if you must, you can restart a WinForms application with `Shell(Application.ExecutablePath)`

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If MessageBox.Show("Start from scratch?", "Confirm Restart", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) = DialogResult.Yes Then restart()
End Sub

Private Sub restart()
    Shell(Application.ExecutablePath, AppWinStyle.NormalFocus, False)
    End
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I am working on Alejandro's suggestion. Some success, but not all there yet.